# java remote debug with jetty and IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jetty, jdb

I have a SpringMvc based application project hosted in Jetty and managed by Maven3.  I want debug program in remote server JVM. So, on the server side I set java options to the Jetty server.

```
-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=10.0.5.60:50019,server=y,suspend=n
```

Then start the jetty server.
[jetty server listening on the debug port](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OYd6Y.png)
Everything seems fine. Then I config a remote profile in IntelliJ
[IntelliJ remote debug profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7iZNz.png)
 And start Debug, console shows

```
Connected to the target VM, address: '10.0.5.60:50019', transport: 'socket'
```

Wow, seems good. Bug things always happens, The breakpoints can't stop when I visit the running code. That was strange!
I promise I have logs to show that the break-point code must been exec-ed.

So, any one can give a hint to me? Thanks for ur great help.

Comment: If the code of the running application is different to that in the IDE, say if you have added a few lines, then sometimes break points will be missed.

Comment: It migth be relevant, the vm args used above are for Java 1.4.  For 1.5+ Intellij expects: 
`-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005`